# Any idea why my openGL camera is stuttering only on the X axis? and only when using nvidia drivers?

Tags: opengl, c++, camera, windows, nvidia

As part of my assignment, I've been building a scene graph framework in C++/OpenGL.

My camera works absolutely fine going backwards and forwards, but when I strafe / move on the X axis, the camera just starts stuttering. It doesn't make much sense to me, because it's the same principle to move back/forward as it is to move right/left.

Everything is also normalised and being applied by deltaTime, so that's not an issue. Interestingly, this didn't happen when I was using my intel built in gpu, but only started occurring when I forced my nvidia card to handle the program.

Here is a video of the aforementioned stutter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyTIv0yiaP0&feature=youtu.be

My scene graph is available for viewing on my GitHub:

1. The repo: https://github.com/charliegillies/fullmetal.
2. The camera https://github.com/charliegillies/fullmetal/blob/master/fullmetal.cpp (line 503-730, mostly get/set methods.)
3. The camera controller https://github.com/charliegillies/fullmetal/blob/master/fullmetal-helpers.cpp (line 14-204)

Please note that this framework is still in its early days.

Let me know what you think, and I'll be sure to post a fix if I find it.

Comment: It looks like your sky-box is also stuttering, where it shouldn't ever move. That's probably a clue. Also what does "I forced my nvidia card to handle the program"? For something this simple I wouldn't expect you to need to do much to make it work on any video card.

Comment: @user1118321 By "I forced my nvidia card to handle the program", I meant that I turned the option on in the nvidia control panel that ensures that nvidia handles the graphics application. This one: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-WosBIX8W7vQ/UZVm1nOghwI/AAAAAAAABbM/0A_ujuFqn1k/s1600/recap_2014_crash1.png

Comment: OK. I'm not a Windows dev, so I don't know what those options do. But that may also be a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

Turns out I the look at was being simply calculated in the wrong order, the eye variable and position variable were out of sync, which was causing the stutter.

Comment: Remember to mark the question as answered if you solved your problem